# download.01.org certificate verification failed - CRLfile missing?

Tags: apt, package-management, intel-graphics, certificates

So I had intel-Linux-graphics-installer on my computer 
but lately when I

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error

```
Err https://download.01.org trusty/main amd64 Packages                         
server certificate verification failed. 
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

Tried reinstalling intel-linux-graphics-installer but nothing happend.
And various solutions found here on askubuntu.com on certificates problems but didnt end up anywhere.

Any ideas on how to get that CRLfile?
Also is this problem on my side or on the servers side?

Comment: It seems to be a problem on the server. Let's wait and see if it persists.

Comment: @Oli 
The fact that two accounts were created just today and both gave answers that are "dangerous" to go on with, really seems suspicious to me.
[playmobitch](http://askubuntu.com/users/366442/playmobitch)
[XperianX](http://askubuntu.com/users/366436/xperianx)

*End of conspiracism* :P

Comment: The answer here is multiple powers of magnitude more secure than adding new root certificates from an untrusted location (which is why I didn't merge it in and have left this answer). I'll keep an eye on it but I think multiple people suffering from a brand new problem is reason enough that there might be a few new Ask Ubuntu users asking what went wrong.

Comment: My advice would be to just disable your intel-drivers repository for now.

Comment: @Oli I was having the same issue. For now, my solution was to disable intel-drivers repository (safer than "opening the door" for everything. )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can download the certificate manually with `openssl` and add it into your local trusted certificates:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect download.01.org:443 | \
  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | \
  sudo tee '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/download_01_org.crt'
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: That is *much* better but I'm not sure `openssl s_client` validates. If the server is compromised (or undergoing a weird MITM attack), this *could* also be harmful. But again, much better than adding random certs.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Sorry for being a pain. I take security fairly seriously.

Comment: You might want to use `tee -a`, otherwise, you will overwrite your `.crt` file and potentially lose any other certificates you have saved in there.

Answer (score 2):

I've sent a message on 01.org contact form concerning this certificate problem and linking to this thread.

We'll see if it's a man in the middle attack, a server misconfiguration or a new parent certificate unknown on client side.

update, I had a response from intel :

> Appreciate you letting us know.  We are aware of the situation and we are
>   addressing it.  We are updating all our infrastructure to IPv6 and that
>   caused this issue.

Comment: It's working now. :)

Answer (score 1):

How would you go about undoing this fix?  Don't have enough rep to comment, but I figured it might be good to remove the certs once you get the drivers, as it sounds like they'll fix the issue server-side eventually.

I removed `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/download_01_org.crt` and `/etc/ssl/certs/download_01_org.pem` for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

just update certificates

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

worksk like a charm

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't get my drivers updated at ALL yesterday. Glad I found this so soon.

I solved the problem by combining 2 of the given solutions.

First I downloaded the cert with openssl

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect download.01.org:443 | \
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | \
sudo tee '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/download_01_org.crt'
```

Then I updated my CA certs by running:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

After that I just ran the installer. Or if you just want to double check if everything works you can just update via the command line first.

To update via the command line"

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -3):

add this line to your /etc/apt.conf file :

```
Acquire::https::download.01.org::Verify-Peer "false";
```

Comment: I think this is not a good way to solve my problem.
Also as I see it is a problem on the server and so others too experience the same problem.
See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/570890/apt-server-certificate-error-with-download-01-org).
Thanks for the reply