# Apt server certificate error with download.01.org

Tags: package-management, ssl

I should begin by mentioning that I am very new to Ubuntu and I am in the process of getting used to it. 
Every time I try to update it gives me back an error. I have put it here in my question. Please tell me what to do.

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IE                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IE              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IE              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IE                
Err https://download.01.org trusty/main amd64 Packages                         
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Err https://download.01.org trusty/main i386 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Ign https://download.01.org trusty/main Translation-en_IE
Ign https://download.01.org trusty/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

W: Failed to fetch https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```